# Import data from files in same project in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

This is a simple problem but I am struggling to solve it. I have a project open in PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1. I have a .npy file with data, and it's located at src -> folder_name -> numpy_file.npy. Then, I have a Python file under another directory in the same project, located at src -> folder_two -> python_code.py. In my Python file, I attempt to load the numpy file data using:

`np.load('folder_name/numpy_file.npy')`

but it tells me there is no such file or directory.

I have marked 'src' as my Sources Root. What else am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to check your current path with `import os` and `print(os.getcwd())` and navigate from there - you might be in a different folder than you think. As far as i know defining a sources folder does not mean that this is your current working directory. You define such things in the run-configuration at `Working directory`. Also, with `os` you can change directories if that is what you want, e.g. `os.chdir("..")` to go up one folder etc.

---

#### Edit

To further elaborate the problem - i tried reproducing your situation:

1. Created a new pyCharm project in a folder called `src` (pure python, no venv, no welcome scripts)
2. I created the subfolders `folder_one` and `folder_two`
3. Inside `folder_one` i created a text-file with a sample-text called `my_file.txt`
4. Inside `folder_two` i created a python file called `sub_module.py` equivalent to your file.
5. I defined `src` as the sources root (which is not necessary i think): In PyCharm project tree > rightclick src folder > mark directory as > sources root
6. I created a run configuration:

   - Script path: path to your `sub_module.py`
   - Working directory: path to your `src` folder
   - The rest can be empty

Then finally, this is the content of my sub_module.py file:

```
print("Im in folder: " + os.getcwd())

# Here i define which file i want to access - taking for granted we are in the src folder already
other_file = "folder_one" + os.sep + "my_file.txt"

# Here i check if the file really exists
if os.path.isfile(other_file):
    
    # Here i do some operations with the file and demonstrate os.path.abspath, which is not even needed
    print("I can access file " + os.path.abspath(other_file))
    with open(other_file) as f:
        print(f.read())
```

This returns me the content of `my_file.txt`. I also uploaded the zipped PyCharm project [here](https://www.file-upload.com/ay5e1ilecb5v) (where i do not know if it is fully legal). Hope this helps to relate.

Comment: Thank you. Path looks correct or as expected. Going up a directory with ```src/folder_name/numpy_file.npy``` is giving me the same error as well. Hmm.

Comment: So `print(os.getcwd())` returns your `src` folder? Then you should leave out the `src` in the np.load statement. Or simply use the full path to the file if that is possible. Another problem could be that you use the wrong separators, `os.path.abspath()` helps you to get rid of that - (linux uses ` / ` as separator, while windows uses ` \ ` - best is to use `os.sep` wherever possible)

Comment: Yes, it returns the src folder. If I use the full path, it works, but I am unable to use it due to work related constraints. ```'folder_name/numpy_file.npy'```, ```'folder_name\numpy_file.npy'``` and ```'folder_name\\numpy_file.npy'``` all return the same error.

Comment: @pariskey i edited my post - maybe this helps

Comment: Thanks! I had to change my working directory under run configuration

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the current directory where your Python program is executed. If it starts from `folder_two`, then you should open the file by going "up" one level:
`'../folder_name/numpy_file.npy'`

Comment: Unfortunately, going up by using ```src/folder_name/numpy_file.npy``` returns the same error

Comment: if your program is started in `folder_two`, then you are actually trying to access:
`folder_two/src/folder_name/numpy_file.npy`.

My suggestion was to use `'../folder_name/numpy_file.npy'` (the `..` means "go up one level", from folder_two it will go up to src, and then down to folder_name